# How to know programmatically that Adobe Reader finished loading a file?

Tags: c#, c++, pdf, winapi, adobe

I'm writing an app that loads pdf files and gets information about the Adobe Reader process.

My problem is that I don't know when Adobe Reader finishes loading the file. Currently I'm connected to the process as a debugger, so the process obviously runs slower and I don't want to just Sleep() for a few seconds. I don't care if the solution is in C++ or C#, because I can signal an event to my program.

I'm looking for a specific solution for Adobe Reader and hopefully other Adobe readers (like Acrobat Reader DC for example).

I tried a few solutions:

- I tried to write an Adobe plugin in C++ that can raise an event when adobe finishes loading. That's an easy solution, but the problem is that Adobe want all plugins to Adobe Reader to be signed by them, and that may cost a lot. That's why I dropped that idea.
- I tried using the IAC (Inter Application Communication) according to their manual, but it didn't work for me and honestly it's written very poorly. They are exposing a COM interface, but I can't seem to get it to work.

A solution for me would be even a didFinishLoading() function that I can call once a second, and that I could raise an event once it happened.

I've been struggling for a few days now and would really appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think, the event you are asking for even exists. Adobe Acrobat Reader loads and displays pages on demand. It doesn't load the entire document.

Comment: If you'll look here: http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/pdfl_sdk/9/PDFL_SDK9_HTMLHelp/API_References/Acrobat_API_Reference/PD_Layer/PDDoc.html , you'll see that there is a PDDocDidOpen() function, that's what I need. The problem is that it's accessible only with a plugin...

Comment: If that's the event you are looking for, why aren't you using it? Still though, there's no indication that this event were raised, when a document **finished** loading. More like a callback, after preliminary integrity of the document had been verified, and the internal object representation had been created.

Comment: What is your actual goal?

Comment: I can't use the event because I can't use the plugin I wrote on Adobe Reader. Adobe has this annoying policy that plugins need to be signed and it costs a lot of money. I'm just looking for some other easy solution to know that Adobe finished loading the file. For example, I did it for Word, using a VSTO plugin and registering to an event when Word finishes loading a doc file

Answer (score 0):

Because PDF is random access, the entire file may never load until you force it to. You can inject some JavaScript into the file via IAC that will cause the entire file to get read. Something like "this.syncAnnotScan()" which guarantees that all annotations will be scanned by the time the method returns... even if there aren't any. This means every page needs to be loaded before it can even run. It's not ideal but it does work.